# Excel get max between two cells (NOT RANGE)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The `MAX` function gives me the maximum number in a range but what if my cells are not in a range?

If we have in A1 the number 10m and in D11 the number 8m how can we find the `MAX` number between these two cells?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify a set of cells instead of a range:

```
max(A1;A4;A10;A12)
```

In your case:

```
max(A1;D11)
```

Comment: Just for information: several functions work in a similar way, e.g. SUM, MIN, MAX. All accept a limited number of "arguments" (255 in Excel 2007) which can be either numbers, names, arrays or references (ranges or single cells, for instance), see Excel help. For example you can have =SUM(23,A4,D:D) which will add 23 to the value of cell A4 and the total of column D